# Prove that the integral is well-defined

Tags: integration

We have an integral defined for all $x\geq 0$, $$F(x)=\int_0^\infty e^{-xt}\frac{(1-e^{-t})^2}{t^2}dt$$

The goal is to prove that $F$ is well defined and is continuous on $[0, \infty)$. I know we have to consider the integrand $f(t,x) = e^{-xt}\frac{(1-e^{-t})^2}{t^2}$. We know that $x\mapsto f(t,x)$ is a measurable function, by composition of measurable functions. We know that $t\mapsto f(t,x)$ is a continuous funtion, for all $x\geq 0$, again by composition of continuous functions. We actually only need almost everywhere continuity, so we can ignore 0. Now we need to prove that there is a function $h(x)$, such that $f(t,x)\leq h(t)$ for all $t\geq 0$. I tried dealing with the problematic term $e^{-xt}$ by defining it on the domain $[a, \infty)$ for some $a\geq 0$ and then taking the limit to 0, but that doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: "a function $h(x)$, such that $f(t,x)\leq h(t)$" That's a dangerous argument relabelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Using
$$ e^x\ge 1+x \text{ for }x\ge -1$$
one has
$$ 0\le 1-e^{-t}\le t \text{ or }|1-e^{-t}|\le t. $$
Then you have $h(t)=e^{-xt}$.

Comment: but then we still have $h$ depend on $x$, no?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Can we then define an $a>0$, and let $x\geq a$, and say that $|f(x,t)|\leq e^{-ta}$, with $e^{-ta}$ being summable. Then we can take the limit of $a$ to 0 and conclude?

Comment: Yes, you got it.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to xpaul's answer, you can actually solve this explicitly, by noting that you can differentiate twice with respect to $x$ and then this becomes an easily solved Laplace transform
$$ F''(x) = \int_0^\infty e^{-xt} (1-e^{-t})^2 \ dt = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{2}{x+1} + \frac{1}{x+2}. $$
The solution is given by
$$ F(x) = x \ln x - 2(x+1) \ln (x+1) + (x+2) \ln(x+2). $$

Comment: One must also verify e.g. this gives the correct limits of $F,\,F'$ at $\infty$.

Comment: I believe you just have to check that $F, F' \to 0$. This should not be too difficult. But it is a good point.

Comment: Before that, don't you need to prove that the function is twice-differentiable?